# T-SQL Syntax Issue Else if style logic

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

two questions today, I'm a busy bee and luckily I have an awesome community at my disposal!

My issue here is this:

I have a field i need to update based on existing field data.

```
If Gender = F then foo = 1

If Gender = M then foo = 2

If Gender = Male then foo = 2

If Gender = Female then foo = 1

If Gender is not above then foo = 3
```

Here is what I have:

```
update EmailAddresses 
set Priority1 = '1'
where GENDER__C = 'Female'

update EmailAddresses 
set Priority1 = '2'
where GENDER__C = 'Male'

update EmailAddresses 
set Priority1 = '1'
where GENDER__C = 'F'

update EmailAddresses 
set Priority1 = '2'
where GENDER__C = 'M'

update EmailAddresses 
set Priority1 = '3'
where GENDER__C not in (select 'Female', 'Male', 'F', 'M')
```

Any help much appreciated! And its Friday!! Whoo hoo

Comment: Nevermind. Answers came in whilst I was crafting this comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
update EmailAddresses set
    Priority1 = case GENDER__C
        when 'Female' then 1
        when 'F' then 1        
        when 'Male' then 2
        when 'M' then 2
        else 3 end
```

Comment: You diamond, remembered for next time! Have a good weekend mate.

Comment: If you found the answer helpful, an upvote and accepting the answer would be appreciated ;)

Comment: Of course, standard procedure, the ten min wait is slightly annoying on the accept :)

Answer (score 4):

Change it to a CASE statement :

```
UPDATE EmailAddresses
SET Priority1 = Case
    When GENDER_C IN ('Female', 'F') Then '1'
    When GENDER_C IN ('Male', 'M') Then '2'
    Else '3'
End
FROM EmailAddresses
```